# Finding an array subsection index from one string within it (python 3.4.2)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, indexing

This question is very similar to one I previously asked... but is not the same!
This is my current code (thanks Kasra AD!):

```
def find_index(name,l=sav) :
    for i,j in enumerate(l) :
         if name in j :
              print ('index is : {}'.format(i))
```

You would then enter the name of the string that appeared in the subsection and it would print out the index of the subsection. For instance, if an array was like this:

```
sav = sav = [['Joseph', 'Alex', 'Josh'], ['James', 'Harvey', 'Nat']]
```

and you entered     find_index('Alex') it would print out '0'. However, I want to change it so that if the name appears in the array multiple times only the first time is counted and it stores the result in a variable (as a string). 
I would like the output to just be the index of the first subsection with the name in, stored in a variable.
Any suggestions/solutions are helpful (remember that I am only a beginner). Thanks!

**Edit**
Final output:

```
sav = [['Joseph', 'Alex', 'Josh'], ['James', 'Harvey', 'Nat']], ['Alex', 'Harvey', 'Harry']
```

after running the code to find the index of the first subsection with 'Harvey' in:

```
sub_index = '1'
```

Comment: welcome ;) , for more clarifying its better to add a desire out put !

Comment: Yeah, I know, I didn't realize what I wanted until about an hour ago. Spent that time trying to figure it out, got nowhere. I would like the output to just be the index of the first subsection with the name in, stored in a variable.

Comment: sorry but programmers here specially myself habit to read less and just see the code , so add your expected out put to your question ! sorry again ! ;)

Comment: so its actually like the before function , but you need to `return` the string instead `print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to `return` instead `print` :

```
>>> def find_index(name,l=sav) :
...     for i,j in enumerate(l) :
...          if name in j :
...               return ('index is : {}'.format(i))
... 
>>> find_index('Harvey',sav)
'index is : 1'
```